# Can't scroll in scroll view in kivy

Tags: python, scroll, kivy

I  need a screen with  many buttons,which i am creating in cycle.It  should be scrollable. But when i am executing this code, it  works like the page size equal to scroll view widget, so i can't scroll down, it's reacting like i  am overscrolling  through border.Python code:

```
class List_of_days(Screen):
    date = date
    days = get_last_n(7,date)
    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.days)
        for i in range(0,100):
            self.grid.add_widget(Button(text='ура'))
```

kivy file:

```
<List_of_days>:
grid:grid
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: "Назад"
            on_press:
                app.sm.current = 'menu'
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            ToggleButton:
                text: '7 дней'
                group:'number_of_days'
                id: btn_7days
            ToggleButton:
                id:btn_30days
                text: '30 дней'
                group:'number_of_days'
            ToggleButton:
                id:btn_all_days
                text: 'Все'
                group:'number_of_days'
        GridLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            id:grid
            padding: 10,10
            spacing: 5
            row_default_height:100
            cols: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `kv`, add:

```
height: self.minimum_height
```

to both the top level `BoxLayout` and the `GridLayout`.